# Why does my jQuery AJAX return 0?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm running out of ideas why does my ajax function return 0. I'm trying to get stripe payment and after that my function will try and make a booking through checkfront api.

Any ideas or help is more than welcomed at this point!

Here is my theme's function for AJAX call:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_action_varaa_AJAX', 'varaa_AJAX' );
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_varaa_AJAX', 'varaa_AJAX');

function varaa_AJAX(){
  global $chargeID;
  global $bookingStatus;

  $amount = $_POST['amount'];
  $token = $_POST['stripeToken'];
  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $cardName = $_POST['cardName'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $phone = $_POST['phone'];
  $accept_terms = $_POST['accept'];
  $insurance = $_POST['insurance'];
  $extradates = $_POST['extradates'];
  $id = $_POST['session_id'];
  $form = array(
    'customer_name' => $name,
    'customer_email' => $email,
    'customer_phone' => $phone,
    'accept_terms' => $accept_terms
  );

  function make_payment($token, $name, $cardName, $email, $phone, $amount, $insurance, $extradates) {
    require_once(get_template_directory() . 'vendor/stripe/stripe-php/init.php');
    global $chargeID;

    $stripe_settings = get_option('stripe_settings');

    // Set your secret key: remember to change this to your live secret key in production
    // See your keys here: https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/apikeys
      if(isset($stripe_settings['test_mode']) && $stripe_settings['test_mode']) {
          $secret_key = $stripe_settings['test_secret_key'];
      } else {
          $secret_key = $stripe_settings['live_secret_key'];
      }

      \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey($secret_key);

    // ANONYYMI VARAUS

      // Create customer and assign charge with $token
        $customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(array(
            "source" => $token,
            "email" => $email,
            "description" => "Uusi anonyymi varaus.",
            "metadata" => [
              "nimi" => $name,
              "kortissa oleva nimi" => $cardName,
              "puhelin" => $phone,
              "insurance" => $insurance,
              "extradates" => $extradates
            ]
        ));

      // Get customer id from create above
        $stripeID = $customer->id;

      // Charge customer
        $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
          "amount" => $amount, // Amount in cents
          "currency" => "eur",
          "capture" => false,
          "customer" => $stripeID
        ));

      // Get charge id from charge above
        $chargeID = $charge->id;
  }

  // Create booking
    function create_booking($id, $form){
      require_once(get_template_directory() . 'lib/booking.php');
      require_once(get_template_directory() . 'lib/form.php');
      global $bookingStatus;
      global $bookingId;

      $Booking = new Booking();

      $bookIt = $Booking->create(
        array(
          'session_id' => $id,
          'form' => $form
        )
      );

      $bookingStatus = $bookIt['request']['status'];

      $bookingId = $bookIt['booking']['booking_id'];

      echo $bookIt;

    }

// Run functions above

  // Check WP nonce
    if ( 
        ! isset( $_POST['nonce'] ) 
        || ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['nonce'], 'bookNow' ) 
    ) {

       print 'Sorry, your nonce did not verify.';
       exit;

    } else {
    // Create a customer and charge card
      try {
          // Create charge
            make_payment($token, $name, $cardName, $email, $phone, $amount, $insurance, $extradates);

          // Create booking
            create_booking($id, $form);

          // Check if booking went through
            if ( $bookingStatus = 'OK' ) {
              // Capture charge
                $ch = \Stripe\Charge::retrieve( $chargeID );
                $ch->capture();

              // Booking success  
                $value =  array('msg' => 'success', 'bookingStatus' => $bookingStatus, 'bookingID' => $bookingId );
                echo json_encode($value);

            } else {
              // Refund charge
                $re = \Stripe\Refund::create(array(
                  "charge" => $chargeID
                ));

              $value =  array('msg' => 'error' );
              echo json_encode($value);
            }

      } catch(\Stripe\Error\Card $e) {
        // The card has been declined
          $value = array('error' => true); // or $result = array('error' => false);
          echo json_encode($value);
      }
    }
  die();
}
```

And here is my jQuery AJAX function:

```
                      var token = response.id,
                          amount = vm.total * 100,
                          name = vm.form.name,
                          cardName = vm.form.cardName,
                          phone = vm.form.phone,
                          email = vm.form.email,
                          terms = vm.form.terms,
                          insurance  = vm.form.insurance,
                          action = 'varaa_AJAX',
                          id = vm.sessionId;

                      var nonce = $('#ilmtrail_nonce').val();
                      var extradates = Object.keys( vm.daysBetweenStartStop ).length * 25 - 25;

                          jQuery.ajax({
                            url: AJAXurl,
                            data: { action: action, nonce: nonce, stripeToken: token, insurance: insurance, extradates: extradates, name: name, phone: phone, email: email, cardName: cardName, amount: amount, accept: terms, session_id: id },
                            type: 'post',
                            success: function(value) {
                              if ( value.msg === 'success' ) {

                                console.log(value);
                                vm.form.sending = false;
                                vm.form.sent = true;
                                $('#receipt').openModal();
                                return true;

                              } else{

                                alert ('Jokin meni mönkään. Tarkista tiedot ja kokeile uudestaan, ja jos virhe toistuu ole yhteydessä meihin niin saadaan varaus läpi!');
                                console.log(value);
                                vm.form.sending = false;
                                $form.find('.submit').prop('disabled', false);
                                return false;

                              }

                            },
                            error: function(data) {
                              vm.form.sending = false;
                              $form.find('.submit').prop('disabled', false); 
                              console.log(data);
                              alert ('Jokin meni mönkään. Tarkista tiedot ja kokeile uudestaan, ja jos virhe toistuu ole yhteydessä meihin niin saadaan varaus läpi!');
                              return false;
                            }
                          });
```

Comment: Is there any problem with WordPress itself?

Comment: @MaxYudin Well when I migrated the site to live server it had a problem with urls. So when Im accessing to example.com it redirects me to reinstalling WP. I bypassed this by adding different site url (example.com/test, when WP url is still example.com). I know this was due db migration but I couldn't find any solutions to this. My wp-config.php was matching to db settings etc. (might have to make another question from this error.

Comment: [Duplicator](https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/)

Comment: @MaxYudin I usually use dublicator but this time it didn't work, so I used wp all in one migration.

Comment: Please don't just dump a lot of code. make debuging effort and isolate the problem first

Comment: Have you considered using the REST API/`register_rest_route` instead?

Comment: @MarkKaplun I did make debug effort over 5h today but I couldn't figure this out. And finally decided to come here as my last chance and ask if someone else can point my bug out which I couldn't find my own.. And as I see this worked well and I also did get new way of looking this as Tom J Nowell pointed the possibility to use rest route instead. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies here:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_action_varaa_AJAX', 'varaa_AJAX' );
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_varaa_AJAX', 'varaa_AJAX');
```

Specifically:

wp_ajax_**action_**varaa_AJAX

You didn't replace the word action with varaa_AJAX, it should instead be:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_varaa_AJAX', 'varaa_AJAX' );
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_varaa_AJAX', 'varaa_AJAX');
```

However, I would recommend instead using the WP REST API and `register_rest_route`, which should simplify your code and eliminate these kinds of mistakes.

Comment: Do you have an example of how this could be simplified?

Comment: That would be a new question, and would massively expand the scope of the answer by introducing register_rest_route and other things if I were to put it here, but keep in mind with the REST API, you just return what you want to return, no exit or die statements, no wp_json_encode, etc etc

Answer (score 1):

Your function varaa_AJAX() must echo something to ajax. Also, please include wp_die(); after echo statement.

**Your code**:

```
 add_action( 'wp_ajax_action_varaa_AJAX', 'varaa_AJAX' );
    add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_varaa_AJAX', 'varaa_AJAX');    
    function varaa_AJAX(){      
        echo "Ajax Response";
        wp_die(); 
    }
```

**Edit:**

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_varaa_AJAX', 'varaa_AJAX' );
    add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_varaa_AJAX', 'varaa_AJAX');    
    function varaa_AJAX(){      
        echo "Ajax Response";
        wp_die(); 
    }
```

Comment: That returns 0 aswell. I do have die(); in my original function. Is there any main differences using wp_die(); or die();?

Comment: `wp_die()` can return `WP_Error`object for analysis.

Comment: Remove "action_" from below statement and try: 

add_action( 'wp_ajax_action_varaa_AJAX', 'varaa_AJAX' );

Comment: I have edited my answer